# Is Pakistan or China funding and assisting terrorist insurgents in Afghanistan?

Tags: china, pakistan

According to [Amrullah Saleh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thLI1hZHMJs), Afghan State Minister for Security Reforms:

> we are fighting a terrorist group sponsored and assisted by a nuclear state sitting next to us

Afghanistan has borders with two nuclear states, Pakistan & China.

A Guardian [report](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2010/jul/25/pakistan-isi-accused-taliban-afghanistan) from 2010 says:

> At least 180 files contain allegations of dirty tricks by the powerful
>   agency with accounts of undercover agents training suicide bombers,
>   bundles of money slipping across the border and covert support for a
>   range of sensational plots including the assassination of President
>   Hamid Karzai, attacks on Nato warplanes and even poisoning western
>   troops' beer supply.
>
> They also link the ISI to some of the war's most notorious commanders.
>   In April 2007 for instance, the ISI is alleged to have sent 1,000
>   motorbikes to the warlord Jalaluddin Haqqani for suicide attacks in
>   Khost and Logar provinces.
>
> But for all their eye-popping details, the intelligence files, which
>   are mostly collated by junior officers relying on informants and
>   Afghan officials, fail to provide a convincing smoking gun for ISI
>   complicity. Most of the reports are vague, filled with incongruent
>   detail, or crudely fabricated. The same characters – famous Taliban
>   commanders, well-known ISI officials – and scenarios repeatedly pop
>   up. And few of the events predicted in the reports subsequently
>   occurred.
>
> A retired senior American officer said ground-level reports were
>   considered to be a mixture of "rumours, bullshit and second-hand
>   information" and were weeded out as they passed up the chain of
>   command. "As someone who had to sift through thousands of these
>   reports, I can say that the chances of finding any real information
>   are pretty slim," said the officer, who has years of experience in the
>   region.

Is Pakistan or China funding and assisting terrorist insurgents in Afghanistan?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan_and_state-sponsored_terrorism
Its entirely plausible.

Comment: Afghanistan also borders China via a panhandle.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt updated.

Comment: Of course Pakistan fund terrorists. So does China.... and Russia .... and Saudi Arabia .... and Nato. These questions are incredibly silly and narrow-minded. These states fund all organisations who are willing to perform actions that in the interests of that particular state. For example, much of what now makes up ISIS is/was supported by US-ally Saudi Arabia, and many of their soldiers have been trained by the US army. This goes back many years, obviously, to the cold war even, but the intentions that the US had then, are the same that a country like Pakistan have now.